# Is this a Firefox float bug?

Tags: html, css, firefox

The designer requested a two column content area layout with images in the left column, text on the right with a full width quote under the first image.

The client will enter the content in this CMS-driven site so columns need to expand vertically as needed. There are no background colors on the real site so columns don't need to be equal height.

http://jsfiddle.net/juo0ubjw/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-left">Picture here</div>
    <div class="full-width">
        <blockquote>Blockquote here</blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-left">Picture here</div>
    <div class="top-right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    width: 300px
}
.top-left {
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
.top-right {
    background:blue;
    margin-left:100px;
    width:200px;
}
.full-width {
    background:purple;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
}
.bottom-left {
    background:green;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
p {
    padding:10px;
}
```

It works great in Safari, Chrome and IE. But in Firefox, there's a weird issue with a word hanging out of the div on the right.

My fix: http://jsfiddle.net/rfoc71pe/

I've seen mention on here of a FF float bugs related to infinite widths and white space, but that doesn't seem to be the case here as all my widths are defined and words are wrapping.

Question: Does anyone know why this happened and if it's actually a bug or just a problem with my CSS? I'm also wondering if there's a way to fix it that feels less hacky?  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I really think there some kind of bug. But, I found a fix for your:)
Here it is: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/j0tw53eh).

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="top-left">Picture here</div>
<div class="full-width">
    <blockquote>Blockquote here</blockquote>
</div>
<div class="bottom-left">Picture here</div>
<div class="top-right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 300px
}

.top-left {
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}

.top-right {
    background:blue;
    margin-left:100px;
    width:200px;
}

.full-width {
    background:purple;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.bottom-left {
    background:green;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

p {
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

If you sad, you don't need a color and your purple block will be white. In my solution, you can't see the borders of this block.

Try to write to Mozilla's forum, and describe your issue.